# iOS-Swift5 : how to select current/Todays Date in date picker for preferredDatePickerStyle is .inline

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

I took outlet for datepicker:

```
@IBOutlet weak var datepicker: UIDatePicker!
var selectedDate:String = ""

func datepickerSetup(){ datePicker.locale = .current
    datePicker.date = Date()
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date 
    datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .inline
    
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dateSelected), for: .valueChanged)
}
```

here I am using `valueChanged:`
when I am selecting Today's date not able to call this selector method, I tried other control event but not working, please help me with this

```
@objc func dateSelected(){
        let dateformatter = DateFormatter()
        dateformatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        selectedDate = dateformatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        datePicker.isHidden = true
        viewForCalender.isHidden = true
    }
```

Comment: Is that working when selecting future dates?

Comment: Well, today's date is initially selected ( as you wrote `datePicker.date = Date()`), tapping on today's date again obviously is not "value changed". If you select some other date first, then select today's date, your method should be called as expected.

Comment: can you show the selector method as well, please? And check the name of the date picker. In the code above, there is a space in the middle.

Comment: Instead of `datePicker.addTarget` try `datePicker.delegate = self` and then implement `didSelectRow` of delegate. Then it will work

Comment: yeah @Sweeper so what is the solution for this.

Comment: @hi all, I have to show today date as the default , i used value changed but other control event also not working, please check

Comment: Just call `dateSelected` in `datepickerSetup`? Your expectations are wrong here. It doesn't make sense to "select today's date" when _it is already selected_, does it?

Comment: Oh, are you trying to make a date picker that doesn't have a selected date initially? `UIDatePicker` doesn't do that. Try something like [FSCalendar](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar).